# BigQuery: Dismatching Number of Visits between BQ and GA

Tags: google-bigquery

My query is:

```
select SourceMedium,campaign, sum(sessions) as total_sessions from (
    select
    concat(trafficSource.source,trafficSource.medium) as SourceMedium, trafficSource.campaign as campaign,
    fullvisitorid,
    count(distinct visitid) as sessions
    FROM `api-open-broker.108613784.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) as hits WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190101' AND '20190122'
    and totals.visits = 1
    group by fullvisitorid,trafficSource.source,trafficSource.medium,trafficSource.campaign )
group by SourceMedium,campaign
```

If i matching total number of visits(sessions) between GA i have:

```
This query:
459950
GA:
491035
```

Why?

Comment: There are similar past questions that would probably be useful to read. Did you check the `google-analytics` tag? You can search both that and `google-bigquery` using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery+google-analytics

Comment: You need to count distinct fullvisitoridid + visitid to get unique value.